# Error importing Java libraries in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ivy, playframework-2.5

I'm learning the Java version of Play Framework and I got a doubt while trying to install **Maven Java libraries in the build.sbt** file.

Supposedly, it uses Ivy (which I haven't used before) and following the Play Framework Documentation I wrote the following build.sbt file that includes the Unirest Java library:

```
name := """playtutorial"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    "com.mashape.unirest" % "unirest-java" % "1.4.9"
)
```

Then in a controller I' import the Unirest package:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
```

But when requesting the page that corresponds to that controller, I get the following error message:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You already pulled the resources from maven before compiling?

Comment: Yes. I have pulled the "com.mashape.unirest" % "unirest-java" % "1.4.9" line in the build.sbt file and after, when the process finished, i ran the "compile" command inside the activator prompt. Then i refresh the page and the error continue. Too rare i think...

Comment: Why would you want to use a third party REST API when Play itself is a full blown RESTful web application framework?

Comment: That is an example library that I have choose. Only for test if build.sbt works fine. I could have used another library.

Comment: Have you run `activator update` (or `update` inside activator) or `sbt update` ? @XairoMartínez

Comment: If you add the unirest dependency after running the sbt/activator console, then you need to reload the configurations so that the dependency will be added to the classpath.

Comment: Ok, finally it run properly! I have tried all you say at the same time. Maybe the solution was start the "Scala Compile Server" inside the footer bar in Intellij IDEA IDE but i'm not sure. After all, thank you all. I will repeat all the process to see what have made it works.